# Python - OptionParser

Tags: python

I'm a newbie with python.
Can anyone tell me how to remove "None" output below?

```
def main(argv=None):

    if argv is None: argv = sys.argv

    usage = "%prog [options] [command]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage=usage, add_help_option=False,
                          version="version %s" % VERSION)

    parser.add_option("-v", action="count", dest="verbose",
                      help="print extra messages to stdout")

    # help displays the module doc text plus the option help
    def doHelp(option, opt, value, parser):
        print( __doc__ )
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(0)

    parser.add_option("-h", "--help",
                      help="show help message and exit",
                      action="callback", callback=doHelp)
```

Output:

```
[root ~]# ./test.py -h
None
Usage: test.py [options] [command]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
```

Comment: `__doc__ ` is `None`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `print( __doc__ )` line. This is for [docstrings](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-docstring.html).